# Prove $F: \mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ where $F(x) = \int_a^x f(t)\, dt$ ($a<x$) is surjective

Tags: integration, analysis, functions

Prove $F: \mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ where $F(x) = \int_a^x f(t)\, dt$  ($a<x$) is surjective.

$f$ is continuous and bounded below by $m>0$. Also $a$ belongs to $\mathbb{R}$ (reals).

Comment: If you require $a < x$ then it's not true. Take $f$ to be the constant function $1$ for example. Then the integral gives $x-a$ restricted to $x>a$ which is always positive.

Comment: Well, if you want the condition $a<x$, then the function $F$ is definitely not surjective, because it assumes only non negative values.

Answer (score 2):

OK. The $a < x$ condition is wrong, and makes the theorem false, as others have pointed out. So let's get rid of it.

Let $u \in \mathbb R$ be nonnegative.  Let $x = a + u/m$. Now estimate $F(x)$:
\begin{align}
F(x) &= \int_a^x f(t) ~dt \\
 &\ge \int_a^x m ~dt \\
 &= mx - ma \\
 &= m(a + u/m) - ma \\
 &= ma + u - ma \\
 &=  u 
\end{align}

On the other hand, $F(a) = 0$. So $F$, on the interval $[a, x]$ goes from less than $u$ to more than $u$; since $F$ is continuous (why? it's differentiable, by the Fundamental Theorem, hence continuous.) the intermediate value theorem applies, and there's a value $c \in [a, x]$ with $F(c) = u$. Since $u$ was an arbitrary nonnegative number, $F$ is surjective onto the nonnegative reals.

A corresponding argument, with $x$ again equaling $a + u/m$, where $u/m$ is now negative, applies to negative values of $u$. Thus $F$ is surjective onto the reals.

It also happens to be injective, because it's a strictly increasing function.

Comment: You mean to say that $F$ is a bijection onto the reals.

Comment: I meant to say "surjective" because that's what the OP asked about. I noted it was injective as well, from which one can conclude that it's a bijection, of course.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose it is easier to handle it using derivatives. Clearly $F'(x) = f(x) \geq m > 0$ for all $x$ so that $F(x)$ is strictly increasing. We need to show that range of $F(x)$ is whole of $\mathbb{R}$. Since $F$ is increasing it follows that either $F(x) \to L$ or $F(x) \to \infty$ as $x \to \infty$. If $F(x) \to L$ then it is obvious (by mean value theorem) that $$F(x) - F(x/2) = (x/2)F'(c) = (x/2)f(c) \geq mx/2$$ Then as $x \to \infty$ we get LHS as $L - L = 0$ and RHS as $\infty$. Hence it follows that $F(x) \to \infty$ as $x \to \infty$. Similarly it can be proved that $F(x) \to -\infty$ as $x \to -\infty$. By continuity of $F(x)$ and intermediate value theorem it follows that $F(x)$ takes all values between $-\infty$ and $\infty$ so that the range of $F$ is $\mathbb{R}$ and hence $F(x)$ is surjective.